# Attempting to add custom roles to Azure AD application

Tags: single-sign-on, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, claims-based-identity

I am using the Microsoft Graph Editor to add application roles to a SAML SSO enabled application in Azure AD.  I copied out the existing appRoles stanza using Get and have edited it to include two new roles.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/<objectID>
```

in this case is the objectID of my application.

However, when I run a Patch call to update the servicePrincipals data it throws a very generic error (One or more properties contains invalid values).

I have validated the JSON and am unable to determine what is causing the error.

My JSON is as follows:

```
{
            "appRoles": [{
                            "allowedMemberTypes": ["User"],
                            "description": "msiam_access",
                            "displayName": "msiam_access",
                            "id": "b9632174-c057-4f7e-951b-be3adc52bfe6",
                            "isEnabled": true,
                            "origin": "Application",
                            "value": null
            },
            {
                            "allowedMemberTypes": ["User"],
                            "description": "Administrator",
                            "displayName": "Administrator",
                            "id": "b45591dd-c1f4-404e-9554-18fea972c3e4",
                            "isEnabled": true,
                            "origin": "ServicePrincipal",
                            "value": "SAML_Admin"
            },
            {
                            "allowedMemberTypes": ["User"],
                            "description": "ReadOnlyUsers",
                            "displayName": "ReadOnlyUsers",
                            "id": "e3c19ea4-e86a-4897-9bb5-3d2d115fed80",
                            "isEnabled": true,
                            "origin": "ServicePrincipal",
                            "value": "SAML_RO"
            }]
```

}

I also used a GUID generator to generate the GUIDs.  If and when they are not unique I get an error to that effect.  So, I am ruling that out for now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the *application*, not the service principal.
Custom permissions are defined on the Application object, and are only reflected in the Service principal.

So you'll need to do a PATCH on:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/<objectID>
```

Where objectID is the object id for the Application object (note this is different from the service principal's object id).

You *may* then have to re-create the service principal.

Comment: That is very interesting.  That would mean this entire article is wrong - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-enterprise-app-role-management - which I have been following closely.  I will try your recommendation today and report back.

Comment: Well, I am not 100% sure that this is the only possible way, but it is what Azure Portal does if you add permissions in the manifest.

Comment: You did also have `"value":null` in the original PATCH, which would not be valid by the way.

Comment: Good to know.  The `value": null` was in the original servicePrincipal and I was being careful not to change that. Changing msiam can have unexpected results.

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to try this a bit at some point to check if the docs are right (which they probably are)

Comment: Follow-up:  I added my two role stanzas directly to the application manifest and now I see the two additional roles.  I had to remove the "origin" attribute as the manifest had no idea what that was.  I also tried adding the stanzas to the application using Patch but I received the same "One or more properties contains invalid values" error.

Comment: Is there a downside to editing the manifest? If I save the Enterprise Application does it regenerate/overwrite the manifest?

Comment: If you edit the manifest, it should update the Application object and then refresh the Enterprise Application (= Service principal) from that.

Comment: If you make that an answer I will consider it answered.  I gave up on the Graph Editor and found editing the manifest very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @juunas for helpful feedback.

The only solution that worked for me was to edit the Enterprise Application manifest directly with the new roles.  I used a GUID creator web application to create the GUIDs and everything is working as expected.